# Automate replacing dead seed node

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We deploy our Cassandra cluster in a cloud environment where machines / vms can be restarted and even moved. When a VM is moved, VM retains the IP address but all the data on the VM is lost. We get into a scenario of replacing dead node. Since in our scenario IP address does not change for a VM, we have an automation where we dynamically set 'replace_address' when we detect that the node is the dead node coming back. This works out fine for NON seed nodes.

Problem is with the seed node. I understand that the seed node does not bootstrap automatically when we do 'replace_address'. I also understand that there is a process to replace a dead seed node. But I was wondering on how to automate this with following questions

1. Does removing the IP (dead seed node IP) from the dead seed node Cassandra.yaml is enough to bootstrap the node / dead seed node IP is required to be removed from all the nodes in the cluster.
2. Assuming if I start the dead seed node with 'replace_address' and do a 'nodetool rebuild -- localdc' and 'nodetool repair -pr'. Would this be a alternate option to above option
3. Is there any other better option

Would appreciate any help on this regards

Comment: We are using Cassandra 3.7 version and deploying the cluster on Windows VM's